# ERC-20 Token - Can an user be required to agree to a certification as a condition to making a transfer?

Tags: erc-20, certification

Is it possible to create an ERC-20 token that will display a specific message or require a user to click an acknowledgement as a condition to making a transfer from their wallet to someone else?

If not, is there another way to embed a certification into the code such that users of the ERC-20 token can be deemed to have made a specified certification each time they use it?

Comment: I think you're looking for something similar to EIP-2612. Search for ERC20 with `permit` function

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible with only smart contracts. A contract's transaction either execute successfully or revert. They cannot stop and ask to press a button.

You could combine smart contract and a web application.